# jQuery ignores .replace() after first usage

Tags: javascript, jquery

the following lines of code are supposed to take whatever i type in and replace " " with "-" which works on the first space, but no space thereafter.

```
$('#myinput').live('keypress', function() {  
    var value = $(this).val();  
    value = value.replace(" ", "-");  
    $('#mydiv').text(value);  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

`value = value.replace(new RegExp("\\s", "g"), "-")`

You can also use `"\\s+"`  if you want to replace multiple consecutive spaces with a single `-`

Also look into `input` as an event and `.delegate` as a method.

```
$('#inputdiv').delegate("#myinput", 'input', function() {  
    var value = $(this).val();  
    value = value.replace(new RegExp("\\s", "g"), "-");  
    $('#mydiv').text(value);  
});
```

Relying on [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) , [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) , [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/oninput)

Answer (score 0):

The value.replace does not rely on jQuery at all. It is part of the JavaScript language. JavaScripts String.replace function uses regular expressions. Without further modifiers, the replace function matches the first occurrence of the pattern. You can replace all matches by defining a global modifier, g.

Try

```
value = value.replace( / /g, "-");
```